# How to add AsyncItemWriter in Spring Batch to a Step correctly?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In a Spring Batch Job like the following I'm trying to use an AsyncWriter

```
@Bean
public Step readWriteStep() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("readWriteStep")
        .listener(listener)
        .<Data, Data>chunk(10)
        .reader(dataItemReader())
        .writer(dataAsyncWriter())
        .build();
}

@Bean
public AsyncItemWriter<Data> dataAsyncWriter() throws Exception {
    AsyncItemWriter<Data> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
    asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(dataItemWriter);
    asyncItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
    return asyncItemWriter;
}
```

If I try like this intelliJ complains:

```
Required type: ItemWriter <? super Data>
Provided: AsyncItemWriter <Data>
```

When I change `.<Data, Data>chunk(10)` to `.<Data, Future<Data>>chunk(10)` intelliJ does not make any warning, but when I run the Job, I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Data cannot be cast to class java.util.concurrent.Future Data is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; 
java.util.concurrent.Future is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'
```

For what is the first and the second parameter here? `.<Data, Data>chunk(10)`?

Are these two parameters for what the processor takes and the second what the processor is giving back?

How do I solve this Problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example should compile if you change the step definition to use the following:

```
.<Data, Future<Data>>chunk(10)
```

That said, I'm not sure this will work correctly at runtime because the `AsyncItemWriter` is expected to unwrap items from their enclosing `Future`s, where these `Future`s are created by an [AsyncItemProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/integration/async/AsyncItemProcessor.html).

In other words, `AsyncItemWriter` and `AsyncItemProcessor` should be used in conjunction for this pattern to work. Here is a quick example with both of them:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SO72477556 {

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Data> dataItemReader() {
        return new ListItemReader<Data>(Arrays.asList());
    }


    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Data, Data> dataItemProcessor() {
        return new ItemProcessor<Data, Data>() {
            @Override
            public Data process(Data item) throws Exception {
                return item;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncItemProcessor<Data, Data> asyncDataItemProcessor() {
        AsyncItemProcessor<Data, Data> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<>();
        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(dataItemProcessor());
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        return asyncItemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Data> dataItemWriter() {
        return new ItemWriter<Data>() {
            @Override
            public void write(List<? extends Data> items) throws Exception {

            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncItemWriter<Data> dataAsyncWriter() throws Exception {
        AsyncItemWriter<Data> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(dataItemWriter());
        asyncItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step readWriteStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("readWriteStep")
                .<Data, Future<Data>>chunk(10)
                .reader(dataItemReader())
                .processor(asyncDataItemProcessor())
                .writer(dataAsyncWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) throws Exception {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(readWriteStep(steps))
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SO72477556.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

    static class Data {}

}
```

Comment: Is there any point of using  `AsyncItemProcessor` and `AsyncItemProcessor` if there will be no logic in processor? Isn't this pattern is for bottleneck in processor? Wouldn't multithreading be better in this type of situation?

Comment: @Kaepxer Sure there is no point in that. The example in the answer uses a no-op item processor and item writer on purpose (I don't know what logic to put there as it is not described in the question). The goal is to show how to setup such a pattern, which is what the question is all about, but there should be some logic in the processor and writer for sure. Otherwise indeed, a multi-threaded step is better.